# Would this work as a UUID generator in PHP?

Tags: php, uuid

After reading about the "[uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)" function in PHP, I went ahead and scripted this:

```
<?php
echo implode(
    array_map(
        function(){ return dechex(rand(0, 255)); }
        , range(0, 15)
    )
);
```

Am I missing something here? A lot of the other solutions seem overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

```
<?php
srand(1);
echo implode(
    array_map(
        function(){ return dechex(rand(0, 255)); }
        , range(0, 15)
    )
);
```

On my machine, this returns `d764c8cce93255c4478d7aa05d83f3ea` every time you run it (note the `srand` I added). If two separate applications run it with the same seed, the value is guaranteed *not* to be unique. Since PHP determines the seed automatically (since PHP 4.2.0), it's possible this could happen (it's not likely, but may happen).

Comment: Hows this?<?php
srand(1);
echo implode(
 array_map(
  function(){ return dechex(mt_rand(0,255)); }
  , range(0,15)
 )
);

Comment: I will just counter it using `mt_srand`

Comment: Which won't be unique when it runs on the same machine. I don't see what you are trying to achieve? If PHP provides a `uniqid` function, why don't you just use it? Use *more_entropy* if you need it.

Comment: I learned something today about pseudorandom number generators. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been almost 8 years but if you you use linux you can just

```
`uuidgen`
```